# Html.BeginForm MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, submit

I'm not a pro at MVC, it's been a while, but I have not seen syntex like this before, maybe you can help me out here.

I am simply trying to place a button on the page and call code when clicked. Simple enough... I thought.

The Framework for MVC has all been set up, but it's not Razer, I'm not sure what it is, which is why it's confusing. When I invoke this code from my ASPX page, it runs correctly and returns what I expect back from the Controller:

BUT, I want to ONLY invoke this code on a button click. and from doing some research I found code like this:

```
            @using( Html.BeginForm() )
            {
                 @Html.Action("ResetService")%>
                 <input type="submit" value="Send />
            }
```

This snippit above will not run. IT just thrown the first time of text to the browser. Nothing is rendered. I'm not sure what I am doing or missing, but I have a feeling it's something small. Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need, replace it with your `Controller` name (without Controller afterwards)

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("ResetService", "Controller"))
{%> 
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
<% } %>
```

The line below directly calls the action when the page loads:

```
@Html.Action("ResetService")
```

You are really better off reading through the tutorial here and learning the basics, in the long run it will save you a lot of time.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: well, for some reason it builds the button and puts all the text above into the button. For some reason I have to use <%= %> to make things work... What is that????

Comment: That is because it is an older project and uses Form views rather than razor.

Comment: I updated the question to include form engine syntax. You will have to use <% as a begin in place of @ and <% } %> in place of a closing tag. :)